# I just want to write a simple µ in Ruby and Prawn

Tags: ruby, prawn

my head is on the edge of exploding...
How can I encode my string to UTF-8?

I always get this error:
`Arguments to text methods must be UTF-8 encoded`

I use Prawn as PDF Writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`force_encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-force_encoding):

```
"some string".force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

put

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

at first line of your rb file.